# What is default password for user postgres?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I used Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

I have installed PostgreSQL 10.8, for work with elixir and phoenix framework, 
before hand I make new password in postgresql.

```
$ sudo -i -u postgres psql
postgres=# \password
Enter new password:12345
Enter it again: 12345 
postgres=#\q
```

but when I ran my phoenix, I got problem like this:

```
04:28:07.850 [error] GenServer #PID<0.217.0> terminating
** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28P01 (invalid_password) password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:84: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
** (Mix) The database for Lat7.Repo couldn't be created: killed
```

Comment: `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD '12345';`? I never heard about this `\password`, but possibly it works.